# Sistema ERP com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, servidor, erp

Fui contratado para criar um sistema ERP para uma empresa. O sistema seria Web, hospedado na nuvem, desenvolvido com PHP, MYSQL e JavaScript. Além de todas as telas de cadastro, visualização de dados, CRUD, relatórios, busca... Teria que ter comunicação com impressora normal e impressora não fiscal.

É uma grande quantidade de dados e informações, teria 3 níveis de acesso (admin master, gerente, funcionário).

Minha pergunta: É seguro? É recomendável fazer? Levando em consideração que a conexão é boa. Que tipo de servidor preciso contratar? O que mais me preocupa é fazer a impressão de arquivos e a segurança.

Comment: É seguro jogar na nuvem ou desenvolver em php?

Comment: jogar na nuvem.

Comment: A pergunta está ampla, seria melhor dividir ela em outras, cada uma focando em um assunto. Por exemplo "quais cuidados devo tomar ao hospedar um sistema na nuvem" ou "quais riscos corro ao hospedar um sistema na nuvem?"  Não sei se esta pergunta "Que tipo de servidor preciso contratar?" tem um resposta, a melhor generica seria, contrate o melhor que puder pagar.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom dia,
vou tentar colocar aqui um pouco da minha experiência com esse tipo de trabalho.

Quando se trata de segurança, a sua preocupação é extremamente válida pois uma pessoa mal intencionada ou até mesmo por erro de uso da aplicação por parte do usuário podem comprometer a integridade dos dados, lógicamente o bem maior da aplicação.

Por conta de você estar engajado em criar uma aplicação que deverá ser segura e robusta é altamente aconselhável fazer uso de algum framework, pois qualquer framework (os mais conhecidos é claro) foram exaustivamente testados e garantem segurança dos dados manipulados pela aplicação, para citar, existem um framework com uma curva de aprendizado pequena, CakePHP http://cakephp.org/

Extremamente bem documentado inclusive em alguns momentos em Português do Brasil.

Mas de cara você possui um entrave, como seu servidor está remoto e as impressoras obviamente não farão parte da mesma rede, não será possível fazer impressão diretamente para elas, isto é, impressora matricial ou afins.

sendo assim será necessário que o usuário tenha em sua máquina instalado o driver da impressora e a impressão deverá ser feita pelo navegador, isso poderá ser desastroso para impressora fiscal ou matricial, pois o resultado aprensentado poderá ser diferente do esperado :-(

Em relação ao servidor, vai depender muito do fluxo de dados, se a empresa for de grande porte, acredito que deveria ser um servidor dedicado, mas este como imaginado tem um elevado custo, se o orçamento para manutenção do servidor cobrir o custo de um servidor dedicado vá em frente e prefira um servidor dedicado.

Caso não venha haver muita interação com o sistema e este não precisar de alta disponibilidade, prefira os planos compartilhados estes são muito em conta e também conta bom muitos recursos interessantes para manter sua aplicação no ar com baixo custo. Recomendo amplamente a Hostgator https://www.hostgator.com.br/

Abraço e boa sorte na empreitada!

Comment: Pq o hostgator é recomendado?

Comment: Tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta podem e devem ser melhor elaboradas. Para a pergunta, o comentário do @rray explica certinho como a formular corretamente. Quanto à resposta, não é um framework que dará a segurança, apesar de muito facilitar neste quesito, mas sim a equipe que está desenvolvendo. Com relação à hospedagem, tudo vai depender da finalidade. Um sistema crítico, com dados sensíveis de clientes eu jamais colocaria num host compartilhado, para isso contrataria um sysadmin para montar um host na amazon ou digital ocean e prestar manutenção constante.

Comment: @AndreCardoso Agradeço profundamente os comentários, comentei sobre a questão de segurança e o uso de um framework, citei como exemplo o CakePHP mas poderia ser qualquer outro, normalmente um framework possui proteções para injections e realiza criptografia de dados se necessário, em relação a segurança é encorajado usar um para além de questões de sugurança testadas por mantedores normalmente sérios, também ajuda na manutenção dos códigos por aprensentar padrões de projeto pertinente ao framework.

Comment: Senhores quanto a hospedagem conheço muitas empresas, não é minha intenão fazer merchandising para nenhuma, apenas aconselhei a Hostgator pois possui um ótimo uptime, excelente suporte sem contar com serviços extras que outras nem sonham em ter. O sistema pode sim estar em um servidor compartilhado desde que a alta disponibilidade não seja um ponto crucial. tenho sistemas validados junto a Berghem em servidores compartilhados, então me sinto seguro em dizer categoricamente isso. abraço :-)

Comment: @AloisoGomes nesse ponto eu concordo, com relação à segurança. Agora você complementou sua posição sobre o uso do Framework, lógico, seu exemplo foi o CakePHP, já o utilizei muito e pesaria muito bem os prós e contras ao utilizar o mesmo. Pelo que percebi, também explanou sua posição com relação ao servidor, isso foi legal. Minha opinião é que cada caso é um caso, tudo merece uma análise, suas sugestões foram boas porém deve concordar comigo que não precisas em todos os casos, vale sempre uma avaliação da equipe que está desenvolvendo o projeto, mesmo que a equipe seja de um pessoa só.

Comment: @AndreCardoso Assino em baixo o que escreveu, a pergunta como mencionado acima foi ampla, a resposta procurou apenas diminuir essa vastidão. Agradeço a opinião, obrigado mesmo meu caro, forte abraço